# join 2 tables with different column names into 1 without repeating

Tags: php, mysql

```
usuarios
--------
nombre 

contactos
---------
nombre
```

I have an insert page where I can select who is responsible for the task. It can either be a client (contactos) or a registered employee (usuarios). The clients can also be registered in usuarios later on, so they can login.

I need to display in a select (for further insert in db) all the values of usuarios.nombre and contactos.nombre without repeating (in case the clients are also registered).

I'm working on PHP and MYSQL. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't `UNION` do what you want? It removes duplicates by default (you have to use `UNION ALL` to keep duplicates).

Comment: Probably you need to UNION those two tables SELECT nombre FROM usuarios UNION SELECET nombre FROM contactos

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what a `UNION` query is built for. In your case the query would look like:

```
SELECT nombre FROM usuarios
UNION 
SELECT nombre FROM contactos
```

By default this will only return unique hits between the two tables. It will return in a single column.

If, by chance, you didn't want the values to be unique, you would just change it to:

```
SELECT nombre FROM usuarios
UNION ALL
SELECT nombre FROM contactos
```

Now MySQL will deliver every `nombre` record it finds in both tables.